# What does this javascript syntax means: const { headers, method, url } = request;

Tags: javascript, node.js

It's not clear what this syntax means

```
const { headers, method, url } = request;
```

found in this tut https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called `destructuring operator`.

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

Simple example:

```js
var obj={
   "a":2,
   "b":3
}
let {a,b}=obj;
console.log(a,b);
```

From your example, I saw that `request` is an object and the statement is translated to

```
headers = request.headers
```

But you can also apply `destructuring operator` for **arrays**.

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
var [one, two, three] = foo;
console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how it would work?

Comment: @TKoL, updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
const headers = request[0];
const method = request[1];
const url = request[2];
```

if request is an object,

```
const headers = request.headers;
const method = request.method;
const url = request.url;
```

Comment: my bad. updated.

Answer (score 1):

If request is an object, it means:

```
const headers = request.headers;
const method = request.method;
const url = request.url;
```

Comment: not if `request` is an array

Comment: Is there a difference between const {url} and const url ?

Answer (score 1):

It’s called destructuring. Check it out at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
Ie. you can get nested properties inside of an object. In your case it is res

It can be more convenient to access props from an object by destructing props to a local variable instead of writing the whole namespace like request.headers